# How to find out whether item is updating in SharePoint designer workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

Is there anyway we can get when list item updating in sharepoint designer workflow?. I have status ="New" it is need to send only one time when new item created.

But now it is sending emails when item is updating with status="New". So I want check if it is new then only check status="New" and send email. otherwise No.

[image]

Comment: Change the settings of the workflow to start only on item create.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the values of your Current Item's Created column and Modified column in your workflow. If the two datetime values are equal, your Current Item is newly created. Else, your Current Item's been changed.

[Did my workflow run on item changed or item creation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30424/did-my-workflow-run-on-item-changed-or-item-creation)